# Beautiful soup not picking u certain tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Okay, I have read a lot of the answers on here about working with beautiful soup. and still am not having luck getting what I need done here is my

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("/home/brendan/PycharmProjects/untitled2/newDeficency.html"),"html5lib")

for element in soup.find_all('input'):
    print(element['name'], element['value'])
```

Since this is part of a larger program for now I just cached a copy of the page type i'd like to scrape now this currently returns nothing but the following code returns all the hyperlinks in the document

```
for element in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(element['href'])
```

I am unsure why this is not working properly as i have also tried using

```
'li' , 'select' 'option' and 'form'
```

with no success despite them clearly being in the source here is a [here is a link to source page](https://storage.googleapis.com/brendanmorrison.ca/newDeficency.html)

be greatly appreciated as I've been messing with this 6 lines of code for a few hours now and am completely lost

Comment: My attempt to follow the link to 'source page' gave me: {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"lockedDomainExpired","message":"Locked Domain Expired"}],"code":401,"message":"Locked Domain Expired"}}.

Comment: To clarify, you just want to get the 'name' and 'value' attributes for all of the `input` elements for a page?

Comment: sorry I updated the source link, didnt use a public link the first time but yah, im just trying to get name and value of an 'input'

Comment: The problem is that some <input> don't have 'name' and some <a> don't have 'href' . What exactly are you trying to scrape ?

Comment: okay, this could be the case but as Bill Bell showed this  [ inputs = soup.find_all('input');len(inputs) ] should still return a number other then zero .. ANd im attempting to scrape what is essentially a customized phpmyadin panel

Comment: I also get 37 inputs and 61 links. Silly question, but are you sure you're reading the same file ?

Comment: not silly at this point no ... but yah i uploaded the file you used from mine directly and I can print  soup.body and  see the entire output of the body.... I somehow get 81 <a> tags though ...  I am looking into debugging what apparently is my set up now ... are you using beutifulsoup4 ?

Comment: I use python 2.7 with bs4 . `len(soup.find_all('a'))` prints 61. Can you include _all_  the relevant code in your post ?

Comment: soup = BeautifulSoup(open("/home/brendan/PycharmProjects/untitled2/newDeficency.html").read())
print (len(soup.find_all('a')))     Gives me an output of 83

Comment: I'm Starting to think this is due to using python 3.4.3 instead of python 2.x ... nvm I get the same result using python 2.7 with the same code

Comment: Okay I copied the file i posted and get your numbers now . I am not sure what the exact differences between the two are however it seems to be working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you need.

```
HTML = '''\
<html>
<body>
<form>
    <input type='text' name='name' value='jones'></input>
    <input type='text' name='rank' value='private'></input>
    <input type='text' name='serial_number' value='B18567'></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
for element in soup.find_all('input'):
    print (element.attrs['name'], element.attrs['value'], element.attrs['type'])
```

Output:

```
name jones text
rank private text
serial_number B18567 text
```

EDIT: You should see something like this in the browser window when you open the file you've downloaded in the browser.

[image: upper left corner of browser window]

Now, in Windows Ctrl-A, Ctrl-C and put clipboard contents into a file called `temp.htm`.

Comment: Hey thanks, and although this works it doesn't seem to work with the source files I need.  the find_all function is not returning anything

Comment: I think that's because that code has been tortured enough that it no longer has any `input` elements. It's a page that **does** display `input` elements but it doesn't have any, if you follow me. Do you still have access to the original page?

Comment: I do  follow you and yah , it is definition of spaghetti but this is how it comes straight from the server which is behind a login which is why I posted the source the source does have {<input>}  however i noticed there is no {</input>} but i was under impression from docs html5lib would take care of that?

Comment: It is. :) Helping you, that is. A simple way of getting the HTML is to load what you've downloaded into a browser then copy-paste what's in the browser window into a text file — let me call it temp.htm — and run something like the following. `soup = BeautifulSoup(open('temp.htm').read(), 'lxml');inputs = soup.find_all('input');len(inputs)` Result for me is 37.

Comment: really? maybe its something with my set-up ? cause i still get 0 as a result and I get a result of 1 for 'table' despite there being atleast 3 or 4 of them ... I'm using beutifulsoup4 with python  3.4.3

Comment: See edit to be clear what I meant. So, yes, really. We were talking about `input` elements, not `table` elements. But I find that there are 18 `table` elements.